# How to disable mousewheel events on dijit.form.NumberSpinner widgets?

Tags: javascript, events, dojo, dom-events, mousewheel

I'm using some `dijit.form.NumberSpinner` widgets in my dojo-based application, all of them are connected to `onChange` actions.

A problem occurs when one has an area with lots of `NumberSpinner`s: Users scroll across the page and accidentally fill the `NumberSpinner` fields with unintended values while scrolling with the mousewheel all over the area.

Is it somehow possible to disable mousewheel events on `dijit.form.NumberSpinner` widgets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you never need it, and if you have access to the dojo sources and are able to do your own builds, comment this line on dijit/form/_Spinner.js :

```
postCreate: function(){
    // [...]
    // this.connect(this.domNode, !has("mozilla") ? "onmousewheel" : 'DOMMouseScroll', "_mouseWheeled");
    // [...]
}
```

Alternatively, you can set the intermediateChanges property to true on your widget, and do something like this :

In your html :

```
<input id="spinner1" name="someNumber" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.NumberSpinner" data-dojo-props="value:'1000',smallDelta:'10',constraints:{min:9,max:1550,places:0}, intermediateChanges:'true'"/>
```

In your javascript block :

```
dojo.ready(function(){
    var spinner = dijit.byId("spinner1");
    var currentValue = spinner.get('value');
    dojo.connect(spinner, "onChange", function(value){
        currentValue = value;
    });
    dojo.connect(spinner.domNode, (!dojo.isMozilla ? "onmousewheel" : "DOMMouseScroll"), function(e){
        spinner.set('value',currentValue);
    });

});
```

Comment: customizing the sources as you described and making an own build perfectly worked out for me, thx. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to have the mousewheel only work when the widget has focus is to add `if (!this.focused) return;` to the top of `_mouseWheeled` in `dijit/form/_Spinner.js`.

```
_mouseWheeled: function(/*Event*/ evt){
    // summary:
    //      Mouse wheel listener where supported
    if (!this.focused) return;
    ...
```

The proper way though would be to extend the widget.

```
// Disable _mouseWheeled when not in focus.
require(
    [
        "dojo/_base/lang"
        , "dojo/_base/event"
        , "dijit/form/_Spinner"
    ]
    , function(
        lang
        , event
        , _Spinner
    ){
        lang.extend(_Spinner, {
            _mouseWheeled: function(/*Event*/ evt){
                // summary:
                //      Mouse wheel listener where supported

                if (!this.focused) return;

                event.stop(evt);
                // FIXME: Safari bubbles

                // be nice to DOH and scroll as much as the event says to
                var wheelDelta = evt.wheelDelta / 120;
                if(Math.floor(wheelDelta) != wheelDelta){
                    // If not an int multiple of 120, then its touchpad scrolling.
                    // This can change very fast so just assume 1 wheel click to make it more manageable.
                    wheelDelta = evt.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;
                }
                var scrollAmount = evt.detail ? (evt.detail * -1) : wheelDelta;
                if(scrollAmount !== 0){
                    var node = this[(scrollAmount > 0 ? "upArrowNode" : "downArrowNode" )];

                    this._arrowPressed(node, scrollAmount, this.smallDelta);

                    if(!this._wheelTimer){
                        clearTimeout(this._wheelTimer);
                    }
                    this._wheelTimer = setTimeout(lang.hitch(this,"_arrowReleased",node), 50);
                }
            }
        });
    }
);
```